# tick removal with pfgplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

To remove the ticks of a figure (and not the tick labels), I could only find the opacity trick, that I find odd. Is there any better way?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={color=black!20,line width=0.25pt},major grid style={color=black!30,line width=0.35pt},tick style={opacity=0}}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[grid=both,scale only axis,width=7cm,height=5cm,xmin=0,xmax=2.4,ymin=1e-008,ymax=0.01,,axis background/.style={fill=black!3},xlabel=$\omega$,ylabel=$|X_5(\omega)|$,xtick={0,0.4,0.8,1.2,1.6,2,2.4},xticklabels={$0$,$$,$50$,$$,$100$,$$,$150$},ytickten={-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2},yticklabels={$10^{-8}$,$$,$10^{-6}$,$$,$10^{-4}$,$$,$10^{-2}$}]
\addplot[color=blue,solid]
coordinates{(0,6.09811e-005)(2.4,6.10675e-003)};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use `tick style={draw=none}`.  This has the added flexibility in that you could change the color of the ticks with something like `tick style={draw=red}`