# ytick=\empty not working with semilogyaxis

Tags: pgfplots

see what's below. I can't compile it. It works with `xtick=\empty` though.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[ytick=\empty]
\addplot[mark=square*,blue]
coordinates{(1, 1)(2, 5)(3, 20)};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: where can i get this bugfix? i have the same problem ...

Comment: @Joseph unfortunately, it was the first bugfix AFTER the stable release. I hope to make the next bugfix release before christmas (or after christmas).

Comment: @Alex you can get the bugfix at http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/ -- download the "unstable" version and install it into some local directory. The pgfplots manual contains instructions how to adapt your TeX installation to use the local directory.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger That's why for `siunitx` I have two branches :-) Thanks for the update.

Comment: @Joseph I can "best" that: currently, I have 7 for pgfplots :)  (stable, master, unstable, and some very special feature branches which are more-or-less in experimental state). But nevertheless, the release cycles are still longer than I would like. Releasing always takes at least two days of careful work to avoid stupid compatibility mistakes :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ytick={}` should do the trick.

Alternatively adapting the solution from [tick removal with pfgplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24662/tick-removal-with-pfgplots/24664#24664)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[ytick style={draw=none}]
\addplot[mark=square*,blue]
coordinates{(1, 1)(2, 5)(3, 20)};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not for me, unfortunately. It looks like it is a bug since it is wroking well with `axis`.

Comment: See updated solution.

Comment: thanks but it's still a problem since the exact same code with `xtick` works fine.

Comment: Submit this as a pgfplots possible bug report [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=224188&atid=1060656) by clicking on the *Add new* link.

Comment: @Werner thanks for the report, I read it here. I confirm that this is a bug - sorry about that. I have a preliminary bugfix ready at hand.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Did this bug get fixed in the release version of `pgfplots`?

Comment: My workaround is `ytick={1e-15},ymin=1e-11,ymax=1e-7`. With `ytick={}` I got a compilation error, with `ytick style={draw=none}` the ticks were still there.